# How can I add clothes to a character in Blender that I animated in mixamo?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

imgur gif uploads never work for me for some reason, but [here is a gif of my issue.](https://imgur.com/a/joKoiwP)

My Blend file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tiXFtiByppthLnM-1Hcwu2kkay6_zp3A/view?usp=drive_link) if needed.

Used mixamo for the first time today, when i uploaded my character to rig on their website, it only worked with my character not wearing clothes, so now I have to add the clothes onto the character in blender, which is where i am running into problems.

I have been at this for a while and cant figure out how to attach my sweater, pants and shoes to my character and have these clothes follow the mixamo animation.

First I tried parenting the sweater to the armature deform using automatic weights, but this didn't work as I sort of expected. So I figured doing a data transfer and taking the vertex groups and their weight info from the body mesh and adding it to the sweater would work, but this just gave me some really messed up looking results as can be seen in the video.

I noticed that the sweater seems to move down when being deformed by the armature from mixamo which im assuming has something to do with the issue im having, not sure about this one though. I tried applying the location of the rig and sweater, but it didnt change this at all so idk...

Thanks for reading, any help is super appreciated on this one. I would like to start using mixamo more going forward, but i cant just not clothe any of my characters lol

Comment: You need to put on the clothes in the model's *Rest Position* and then transfer the weights. But it looks like you put them on in the *Pose Position* (first frame of the animation). If you switch the armature to *Rest Position* you will see the problem. The model will "float" above the clothes because they have not the same *Rest Position* as the model.

Comment: This helped thanks! Its alot better now, but parts of my shirt still look pretty messed up. How come my rest pose is different then my then in pose mode? Also, what settings do you recommend if any for my data transfer?